# Can any Qiskit circuit be converted to a gate?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-circuit, pauli-gates

I am trying to convert the following qiskit QuantumCircuit to a gate using [to_gate() method](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.19/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.to_gate.html).

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.opflow import I, X, Y, Z

# construct one qubit circuit
circuit = QuantumCircuit(1, name='R')
    

# append gates as Pauli strings
circuit.append(0.5*I - 1j*np.sqrt(1-0.5**2)*Y, [0])



circuit.to_gate()
```

But I end up getting the following error.

```
QiskitError: 'One or more instructions cannot be converted to a gate. "circuit-304" is not a gate instruction'
```

Are there limitations to the use of to_gate()? Bing AI tells me

> All instructions in the circuit must be gates.

But I cannot find a reference to this, and if that indeed must be true, I do not know how to enforce this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qiskit distinguishes operations into unitary operations ("gates") and operations that are not necessarily unitary ("instructions"). In your workflow you end up with an `qiskit.circuit.Instruction` object on the circuit, therefore it cannot be converted to a `qiskit.circuit.Gate`.

Since you're trying to construct a gate essentially from a matrix, you could instead use

```
U = (0.5*I - 1j*np.sqrt(1-0.5**2)*Y).to_matrix()
circuit.unitary(U, [0])
gate = circuit.to_gate()
```

Alternatively, you could construct the unitary directly

```
from qiskit.extensions import UnitaryGate

gate = UnitaryGate(U)  # U from above
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cryoris' answer resolved the issue I had. Since  [qiskit.opflow is getting depreciated](https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/opflow.html), here's another solution using [qiskit.quantum_info.SparsePauliOp](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.SparsePauliOp.html).

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp

circuit = QuantumCircuit(1, name='R')

theta=0.5
operator = SparsePauliOp(["I", "Y"], coeffs = [theta, -1j*np.sqrt(1-theta**2)]).to_operator()

circuit.append(operator, [0])

circuit.to_gate()
```